# Rewriting queries JOIN as EXISTS

Tags: database, oracle, left-join, exists

I am trying to understand rewriting queries from EXISTS as JOIN and Viceversa.

So I have this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cd83/41)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table store
(
  storeKey number,
  storeName varchar2(500),
  storeLocationKey number,
  constraint StorePK primary key(storeKey)
);

create table storeLocation
(
  storeLocationKey number,
  storeLocationName varchar2(500),
  storeCountry varchar2(500),
  constraint StoreLocPK primary key(storeLocationKey)
);

insert into store values(1, 'Le Store', 1);
insert into store values(2, 'La tiendinha', 2);
insert into store values(3, 'The SuperHyperMegaStore', 3);
insert into store values(4, 'Le Other Store', 1);
insert into store values(5, 'La tienda', 4);
insert into store values(6, 'Chiquinha Tienda', 2);
insert into store values(7, 'Pecorela Tiendinha', 3);
insert into store values(8, 'Le Petit Store', 1);
insert into store values(9, 'Tienda Cipote', 4);
insert into store values(10, 'Tienda Desconocida', 0);


insert into storeLocation values(1, 'Camps Elisees', 'France');
insert into storeLocation values(2, 'Brasilia', 'Brasil');
insert into storeLocation values(3, 'Boston', 'USA');
insert into storeLocation values(4, 'San Salvador', 'El Salvador');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT store.*
FROM store
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeLocation
    ON store.storeLocationKey = storeLocation.storeLocationKey
WHERE storeLocation.storeCountry <> 'France'
ORDER BY store.storeKey ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cd83/41/0)**:

```
| STOREKEY |               STORENAME | STORELOCATIONKEY |
|----------|-------------------------|------------------|
|        2 |            La tiendinha |                2 |
|        3 | The SuperHyperMegaStore |                3 |
|        5 |               La tienda |                4 |
|        6 |        Chiquinha Tienda |                2 |
|        7 |      Pecorela Tiendinha |                3 |
|        9 |           Tienda Cipote |                4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM store
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM storeLocation
        WHERE storeLocationKey = store.storeLocationKey
            AND storeCountry <> 'France'
        )
ORDER BY storeKey ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cd83/41/1)**:

```
| STOREKEY |               STORENAME | STORELOCATIONKEY |
|----------|-------------------------|------------------|
|        2 |            La tiendinha |                2 |
|        3 | The SuperHyperMegaStore |                3 |
|        5 |               La tienda |                4 |
|        6 |        Chiquinha Tienda |                2 |
|        7 |      Pecorela Tiendinha |                3 |
|        9 |           Tienda Cipote |                4 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-----------------------------

SELECT store.*
FROM store
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeLocation
    ON store.storeLocationKey = storeLocation.storeLocationKey
where storeLocation.storeLocationName is null
ORDER BY store.storeKey ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cd83/41/2)**:

```
| STOREKEY |          STORENAME | STORELOCATIONKEY |
|----------|--------------------|------------------|
|       10 | Tienda Desconocida |                0 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
SELECT store.*
FROM store
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM storeLocation
        WHERE storeLocationKey = store.storeLocationKey
        )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cd83/41/3)**:

```
| STOREKEY |          STORENAME | STORELOCATIONKEY |
|----------|--------------------|------------------|
|       10 | Tienda Desconocida |                0 |
```

from here, I have a few (dumb) questions:

- Why Queries 2 and 4 have to be correlated (when I didn't correlate the query, it returned nothing)? Does exists/not exists have to be correlated to work?
- What are the scenarios where it is better to work with either of them?
- Does it make a difference working with a large set of data (DW)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

Actually, if you don't correlate your subquery, your Query 2 will return every row not in France ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cd83/42)). That's because the correlated query: "Return rows from store where there exists at least one ***matching*** row in storelocation that is not in France". Your uncorrelated query means "Return rows from store where there exists at least row in storelocation that is not in France". Since the subquery will always return at least one row, the `WHERE` condition is always true.

In the case of query 4, without the correlation, the subquery will still always return a row, the `WHERE` condition will always be false and you'll get no rows.

Question 2:

If it were me, since you're not selecting anything from `storelocation`, I'd use the `EXISTS` version. It seems clearer to me that the only thing you care about is whether or not there is a matching row in storelocation than in the join case.

This is a simple enough query that I suspect the optimizer will come up with the same execution plan, but I don't know that for sure.

Also, I've seen cases where the `EXISTS` clause allows the optimizer to stop looking for rows once it finds a match rather than having to do the full join.

You obviously wont in this case, but if your storelocation had multiple locations with the same id, the number of rows in the two cases would be different.

Question 3:

There really is no way to answer this without seeing an execution plan. I would write your query in the way that makes it most clear to a reader what you're trying to do, then test it. If the time it takes to run is acceptable, stop. Only if it is too slow should you try to make it run quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the explicative answer, @eaolson. So, basically: If EXISTS as at least a returning row, the outside query will return a value, and NOT EXISTS won't return any value if a value is returned on a inner query, right?

For number 2, I have a question though: How could you select something from the storeLocation table if it is inside a exists? Would you have to join it?

Thanks again.